# bundler install specific group

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

bundler supports [grouping dependencies](https://bundler.io/guides/groups.html). given a a Gemfile like

```rb
# Gemfile

# global gems
gem "foo"

group :production do
  # production gems
end

group :development do
  # development gems
end
```

what is the best practice to install a specific group only [without remembering the option](https://bundler.io/v2.5/man/bundle-config.1.html#REMEMBERING-OPTIONS)? e.g. (only `production` group)

Comment: You have already linked to the docs at https://bundler.io/guides/groups.html. What do you want to know that is not explained by that doc?

Comment: @matt: i've updated the post. specifying with/without is remembered between bundle commands and stored in its configuration files. how can this be avoided?